# update associated collections in MEAN

Tags: angularjs, express, mongoose, mean-stack

i am building a MEAN stack web application, 
i have two associated collections **categories** and **brands**.

now, when i add a new brand and choose its category automatically the category id save in brand schema, 
but i don't know how to update (set to empty) this field (category-id in brand schema) when i delete the category from Category schema...
 hope I made my problem clear .

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

  const categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  categoryname: { type: String, required:true},
  categoryBrands: [{
     type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     ref: "Brand",
     required: true }]
    });
 module.exports = mongoose.model('Category', categorySchema);
```

brands Collection schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const brandSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   brandName: { type: String, required: true },
   brandCategory: {
       type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
       ref: "Category",
       required: true
    }
  });
  module.exports = mongoose.model('Brand', brandSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reference the **Categories** Schema in your js file where you want to execute Schema queries then

Following are the ways on *model* object you can do any of the following to remove document(s):

```
yourModelObject.findOneAndRemove(conditions, options, callback)

yourModelObject.findByIdAndRemove(id, options, callback)
```

Also check this [this](https://blog.hellojs.org/creating-relationships-between-schemas-in-a-document-based-database-like-mongodb-1f965aecc035) it might help you